# Mosquitto is not updating persitance messages (mosquitto.db)

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

Im using Mosquitto as broker and paho mqtt(python) as client. and Im trying to store messages(persistance) in mosquitto.db file. But nothing is happening. Not even mosquitto.db is being created.

Below is the config. file(mosquitto.conf) placed in "conf.d" folder for default local configurations. any help?

```
pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true

persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

persistent_client_expiration 14d

persistence_file mosquitto.db

autosave_interval seconds 10

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely candidate is that the mosquitto user does not have permission to write to the /var/lib/mosquitto directory.